# Fetching data from ContentProvider and making http requests inside Activity life cycle

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

I need to do two consecutive operations when my app starts:

1) fetch some data through a `ContentProvider` from an `sqlite` database,

2) make a http request (or multiple) to fetch data from an outside service.

At what point in the Activity lifecycle should I start an AsynTask that performs these operations? Is `onCreate` in fine? Will I have access to all objects (both ContentProvider and anything I might need for a http request) if I run it at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onCreate` is a good place to initiate this action. But remember since `onCreate()` will be called only once throughout the life of Activity, so you should hold data also.

Also, if you have `splash screen` in your app and this Activity ( in which you are fetching data ) is next to splash screen, then i personally would fetch all the data in splash screen, it will save some time as splash screen non-operational screen and i use this screen for initialization of heavy resources.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it in your onCreate method.
But be careful. Don't block the UI thread.
let the use see something when you are fetching data from your local database or when you are calling a webervice.
You can display an indeterminate progress bar during your background process.